# How to peek all messages in Azure Service Bus queue?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus

I'd like to peek all messages from several Azure Service Bus queues. After that I want to filter them after queueName, insertDate and give the opportunity to make a full text search on the body.

Currently, I'm using the `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` package to create a `ManagementClient` for gathering queue information and then use a `MessageReceiver` to peek the messages.

```
var managementClient = new ManagementClient(connectionString);

var queue = await managementClient.GetQueueRuntimeInfoAsync(queueName);

var count = queue.MessageCount;

var receiver = new MessageReceiver(connectionString, queueName);

var messagesOfQueue = new List<Message>();

for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
   messagesOfQueue.Add(await receiver.PeekAsync());
}
```

Is there a better way to get all messages? Or is there even a way to only peek messages that apply to a filter?

I've also tried to use the `QueueClient.PeekBatch` Method from the `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` package. But that method didn't return all messages although I've set the correct `messageCount` parameter.

And then there is also the package `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`... What's up with all these packages?

So which of the packages should I use and what is the best way for peeking messages of queues based on some filters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution I'm currently using and which works as expected looks like this:

```
var receiver = serviceBusClient.CreateReceiver(queueName);

var messagesOfQueue = new List<ServiceBusReceivedMessage>();
var previousSequenceNumber = -1L;
var sequenceNumber = 0L;

do
{
  var messageBatch = await receiver.PeekMessagesAsync(int.MaxValue, sequenceNumber);

  if (messageBatch.Count > 0)
  {
    sequenceNumber = messageBatch[^1].SequenceNumber;

    if (sequenceNumber == previousSequenceNumber)
      break;

    messagesOfQueue.AddRange(messageBatch);

    previousSequenceNumber = sequenceNumber;
  }
  else
  {
    break;
  }
} while (true);
```

It uses the nuget package `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're receiving a single message from the receiver. A better option would be to receive messages in batch using [`PeekBatchAsync(Int64, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagereceiver.peekbatchasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_MessageReceiver_PeekBatchAsync_System_Int64_System_Int32_) method of [`MessageReceiver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagereceiver?view=azure-dotnet).

Here's the sample code to do so (untested though):

```
var messagesOfQueue = new List<Message>();
var sequenceNumber = 0;
var batchSize = 100;//number of messages to receive in a single call
do
{
    var messages = await receiver.PeekBatchAsync(sequenceNumber, batchSize);
    messagesOfQueue.AddRange(messages);
    if (messages.Count > 0)
    {
        sequenceNumber = messages[messages.Count-1].SequenceNumber;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
} while (true);
```

Comment: Okay but as I said I've already tried the PeekBatch Method and couldn't peek all messages in one batch. Or is the maximum amount of messages restricted to 100 and I have to call the PeekBatch Method multiple times?

Comment: I think you tried PeekBatch message from the older SDK. Can you try it using the latest SDK (Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus). Regarding the batch size as 100, that was just a random number I chose. Yes, with this approach you will need to call PeekBatch message multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Based on your comment I figured out a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

The solution avoids getting the message with the same SequenceNumber twice.

Sequence numbers monotonically increase. And I've tested most cases except rolling over sequenceNumber to 0 when it reaches the maximum value (Long.MaxValue).

```
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

private static async Task<List<ServiceBusReceivedMessage>> PeekAllMessages(string serviceBusConnectionString, string queueName)
{
    var client = new ServiceBusClient(serviceBusConnectionString);
    var receiver = client.CreateReceiver(queueName);

    var messages = new List<ServiceBusReceivedMessage>();

    var batchSize = 20;
    var sequenceNumber = 0L;
    do
    {
        var messageBatch = await receiver.PeekMessagesAsync(batchSize, sequenceNumber);

        if (messageBatch.Count <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Increasing the SequenceNumber by 1 to avoid getting the message with the same SequenceNumber twice
        sequenceNumber = messageBatch[^1].SequenceNumber + 1;

        messages.AddRange(messageBatch);

    } while (true);

    return messages;
}
```